# Compute the centre of mass of 1/4th of sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the coordinates of the centre of mass for the region
>
> $$K:\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2, \quad x\geq 0, \quad z\geq 0\}.$$

This problem should be easy, but I can't see where I make the error. Drawing out $K$, I find it's just a $1/4-$th sphere, cut by the $xy$ and $yz-$axis. Due to symmetry we have that $y_{cm}=0$ and $x_{cm}=z_{cm}.$ $D$ is the semi-circle on the $xy-$plane. The formula for the $x$ (and $z$) coordinate of the centre of mass is

$$x_{cm}=z_{cm}=\frac{\iiint_K x \ dxdydz}{\iiint_K \ dxdydz}=\frac{1}{m}\iiint_K x \ dxdydz=\frac{I_{x,z}}{m}.$$

So,

$$m=\iint_D \sqrt{R^2-(x^2+y^2)} \ dx dy=\iint_Er\sqrt{R^2-r^2} \ drd\theta=\pi\int_0^Rr\sqrt{R^2-r^2} \ dr=\frac{\pi R^3}{3}.$$

And

$$I_{x,z} = \iint_Dx\sqrt{R^2-(x^2+y^2)} \ dxdy=\iint_Er^2\cos{\theta}\sqrt{R^2-r^2} \ dr d\theta = 2\int_0^Rr^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2} \ dr.$$

This is where I'm stuck. That last integral is quite unpleasant. Any suggestions?

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry gimusi, sometimes I froget to do this. Thanks for reminding med and I reallt appreciate all your excellent help!

Comment: Thanks! I'm very happy when we can do math togheter!

Comment: What are your credentials? Are you a student or do you work?

Comment: I will always be a student! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use a change of variable

$$r=R\cos \alpha \implies 2\int_0^Rr^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2} \ dr
=2\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^0  R^2\cos^2 \alpha\sqrt{R^2-R^2\cos^2 \alpha} (-R\sin \alpha)\ d\alpha
=2R^4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \cos^2\alpha \sin^2 \alpha \ d\alpha
=\frac{\pi R^4}8$$

Comment: Neat! However I wonder why Wolfram alpha could not evaluate that integral?

Comment: @Parseval which one?

Comment: The hard one, the one you did. By the way, would that change of variable also work with $r=R\sin{\alpha}$?

Comment: @Parseval Maybe because you had the parameter R inside? Yes of course $r=R\sin{\alpha}$ is also good.

Comment: Could you please fill in the details? I don't se how your bounds change from $R$ to $\pi/2$?

Comment: @Parseval Yes I've skipped some step in the hint but it should be straightforward.

Comment: Ahh.. I see it now! Thanks man, you're the best!